# Matlab, economy QR decomposition, control precision?

Tags: matlab, decomposition, orthogonal

There is a `[Q,R] = qr(A,0)` function in Matlab, which, according to documentation, returns an "economy" version of qr-decomposition of A. `norm(A-Q*R)` returns ~1e-12 for my data set. Also `Q'*Q` should theoretically return I. In practice there are small nonzero elements above and below the diagonal (of the order of 1e-6 or so), as well as diagonal elements that are slightly greater than 1 (again, by 1e-6 or so). Is anyone aware of a way to control precision of `qr(.,0)`, or quality(orthogonality) of resulting Q, either by specifying epsilon, or via the number of iterations ? The size of the data set makes qr(A) run out of memory so I have to use qr(A,0).

Comment: "I assume "economy" stands for an approximation of some sort." No need to assume. The documentation says exactly what it does. There is no approximation relative the "regular" `qr`. It simply means that only the first n columns of `Q` and n rows of `R` are computed. The values should be identical.

Comment: @horchler, your comment should be the (accepted) answer.

Comment: It is very relevant, but does not actually answer the question. So I believe an (upvoted) comment is the right place for it.

Comment: @horcher, thanks for the correction, but the (updated) question still stands :)

Answer (score 2):

When I try the non- economy setting, I actually get comparable results for A-Q*R. Even for a tiny matrix containing small numbers as shown here:

```
A = magic(20);
[Q, R] = qr(A); %Result does not change when using qr(A,0)
norm(A-Q*R)
```

As such I don't believe the 'economy' is the problem **as confirmed by @horchler in the comments**, but that you have just ran into the limits of how accurate calculations can be done with data of type 'double'.

Even if you change the accuracy somehow, you will always be dealing with an approximation, so perhaps the first thing to consider here is whether you really need greater accuracy than you already have. If you need more accuracy there may always be a way, but I doubt whether it will be a straightforward one.

Comment: It is interesting that for `[Q,R,E] = qr(X)` 
`norm(X-Q*R*E')` is several orders of magnitude smaller. Unfortunately, one of the requirements is that first column of X must stay in fixed position so I can't use permutation vector or matrix directly.

Comment: The [Q,R,E] version  improves precision for my dataset, but not for the `magic` matrix.

Comment: + 1 for mentioning horchler ;-)